# Hashmap-Key value should change

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I am working on a programm and i got a lot of data to work with.
With saying a lot, i mean up to 1 million Objects.
My program is working fine, but i need to implement a method for getting any of
these Objects by giving any position.
I'll just demonstrate it:

e.g. i got 1000 cubes (3D Space). All of these Cubes are placed into
a HashMap. The Key of each Object is it's position.
BUT when i move my Object, the position of the Object changes, but my Key doesnt.
So all i want is to set a Key for any Object in a Map which changes by changing a variable of the Object, or is equal to a variable in my Object.
That's my problem. Does anyone know how to deal with this problem or does anyone have any solution ? 
Or is there also any other data structure in Java which could solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with a connection to a database.

For example, using Oracle, you can create a table

```
Cubes(id, position, attribute_1, ..., attribute_n)
```

,and make an operation

```
select * from cubes order by position;
```

Whenever you want, you can update cube's position.

**Edit**: If you don't want to use a database

You can do it with arraylists.

```
ArrayList<Cube> myCubes = new ArrayList<>();
```

And you can order them overwriting the method compare with this way:

```
Collections.sort(myCubes, new Comparator()) {
    @Override
    public int compare(Cube c1, Cube c2) {
        return new Integer(c1.getPosition()).compareTo(new Integer(c2.getPosition()));
    }
}
```

Comment: But it doesnt really sounds very fast. Also i'd like to work inside my program. Not outside with any databases. Or is it the only way`? :S

Comment: Edit: That actually sounds quit nice. Thank you ! :)